# Could Johansen actually have survived the trip by eating the rest of the crew?

Tags: the-martian

Would the corpses of the other 4 crew member really have provided enough meat for her to survive the whole trip?  I'm no expert but it doesn't seem like enough to sustain a person for that long of a trip.

Comment: I refer you to this: https://what-if.xkcd.com/105/ and to this: https://what-if.xkcd.com/78/ clearly if she had rationed it would of been enough.

Comment: They say that human is the other white meat. http://atwitsendcomics.com/comics/index/111/Credible-Source

Comment: Flagged as abusive and downvoted since civil discourse has no place for cannibalism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They aren't suggesting that 4 humans can sustain someone for a year.

The crew would have killed themselves immediately, so they didn't consume any more food. This means whatever they had remaining just increased 5 times for her, since instead of feeding 5 adults, she only is feeding one. She is also the smallest, and therefore requires the fewest calories to survive on the brink of starvation.

With rationing of the remaining food, and apparently consuming her crew-mates, they estimated she could survive. Presumably they were able to calculate the number of usable calories from her crew-mates and factor that into her rationed meal plan for the trip around Mars and back.

Comment: I assumed she was joking when I read that part. Is there any evidence of such a scenario being planned for by NASA or ESA?

Comment: @njzk2 "Just tell mom the supplies would last, okay?" - If that is joking, it is a pretty sick joke to tell your father and to reassure your mother.

Comment: yeah, I found that weird, too. But not much sicker than having planned for that possibility, and asking someone to a/ watch their crew commit suicide b/ eat them c/ live with that memory for many more years.